# Use my own SQLite database vs Import data from csv file

Tags: android, database, performance, sqlite, sdk

I'm currently trying to import ~300.000 lines saved in a file.sql.

After reading few forums, few posts stackoverflow, I found two main solutions :

- Use my own database with android (https://blog.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications)
- Use a csv file or sql file and import it with a transaction

  - [How to populate a large sqlite database on first run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103378/how-to-populate-a-large-sqlite-database-on-first-run)
  - https://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles
  - [Inserting large amount of data into android sqlite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465696/inserting-large-amount-of-data-into-android-sqlite-database)

**What is the best solution, considering the performance aspect, the evolvment aspect (volumetry), the best practises on Android...?
In the perfect case, can I have a example ?**

I'm using ORMlite libray, and classic DatabaseHelper methods like :
onCreate => to import my data 
onUpgrade => to do my migrations scripts (https://riggaroo.co.za/android-sqlite-database-use-onupgrade-correctly/)

*Edit : The database is used for the operations of read-write, and is synchronized with a primary server, in order to obtain and send the changes (using Flatbuffer).
The reason for which I need to import these data is because the synchronization dating of a timestamp 0 (all the lines contained in the base of data of the backend server) is too long at the level of the time.*

Comment: What does "the evolvment aspect (volumetry)" mean? In general, use your own database, but **not** via that awful ancient code. [Use `SQliteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper).

Comment: volumetric evolution about data. the amount of my line (in file.sql), will grow.

Comment: Is this database read-only?

Comment: No, i edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best solution, considering the performance aspect

Shipping a database in assets, and [using `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) to install it as needed, should be much faster than anything involving executing database transactions.

> volumetric evolution about data. the amount of my line (in file.sql), will grow.

Shipping a database in assets will be faster for deploying the app to a new user.

For existing users, neither of your approaches works, and you will need to craft your own code to blend:

- Your new data that you want to ship with the app
- The old data that you already shipped and have on the user's device
- The data that is on the user's device that shipped with *neither* the original nor the updated app (e.g., data from a server, data entered by the user)